# How do I extract a Future[String] from an akka Source[ByteString, _]?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http, akka-stream

I am attempting to stream a file using akka streams and am running into a small issue extracting the results of the stream into a Future[String]:

```
def streamMigrationFile(source: Source[ByteString, _]): Future[String] = {
  var fileString = ""
  val sink = Sink.foreach[ByteString](byteString => fileString = 
    fileString.concat(byteString.decodeString("US-ASCII")))
  source.runWith(sink)
}
```

I'm getting a compilation error:

```
Expression of type Future[Done] does not conform to expected type Future[String]
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to extract the results of the stream?

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more about the use-case? What is the resulting Future going to be used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `Sink.foreach` you'll find the evaluation type is `Sink[T, Future[Done]]` which means it doesn't matter what will happen with the result of the computation of the elements in the stream. Following is the definition:

```
def foreach[T](f: T ⇒ Unit): Sink[T, Future[Done]]
```

On the other hand, the definition of `Sink.fold` evaluates to a `Future[U]` being `U` the type of the `zero`. In other words, you are able to define what will be the type of the future at the end of the processing.

The following is the definition (and implementation) for `Sink.fold`:

```
def fold[U, T](zero: U)(f: (U, T) ⇒ U): Sink[T, Future[U]] =
          Flow[T].fold(zero)(f).toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right).named("foldSink")
```

According to the implementation above you can see that the type to be kept in the materialization is `Future[U]` because of the `Keep.right` which means something like: "I don't care if the elements coming in are `T`s (or `ByteString` in your case) I (the stream) will give you `U`s (or `String` in your case) .. when I'm done (in a `Future`)"

The following is a working example of your case replacing the `Sink.foreach` with `Sink.fold` and evaluating the whole expression to `Future[String]`

```
def streamMigrationFile(source: Source[ByteString, _]): Future[String] = {

  var fileString = ""

  //def foreach[T](f: T ⇒ Unit): Sink[T, Future[Done]]
  val sinkForEach: Sink[ByteString, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach[ByteString](byteString => fileString =
    fileString.concat(byteString.decodeString("US-ASCII")))

  /*
    def fold[U, T](zero: U)(f: (U, T) ⇒ U): Sink[T, Future[U]] =
      Flow[T].fold(zero)(f).toMat(Sink.head)(Keep.right).named("foldSink")
   */
  val sinkFold: Sink[ByteString, Future[String]] = Sink.fold("") { case (acc, str) =>
    acc + str
  }

  val res1: Future[Done] = source.runWith(sinkForEach)
  val res2: Future[String] = source.runWith(sinkFold)

  res2

}
```

Answer (score 7):

If what I'm guessing is right, you want to stream the whole file content into a string. This is best achieved with a `Sink.fold`, a not with a `Sink.foreach`. Example below.

```
def streamMigrationFile(source: Source[ByteString, _]): Future[String] = {
  val sink = Sink.fold[String, ByteString]("") { case (acc, str) =>
    acc + str.decodeString("US-ASCII")
  }
  source.runWith(sink)
}
```

You're probably aware of this, but your file will need to fit into memory for your program to run correctly.